# How to fix a complex Discord command in JS based off of webhooks and roles

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I'm working on a command where when you do the command, d!woa the following happens

> A webhook gets created with a certain name, Then a role gets created with the channel name, after that the bot watches if there's a webhook with that certain name for the channel, and just sees if anyone sends a message in that channel. If it does, then the bot will add that role with the certain name.
> The problem is that there's this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined`
> The error will most likely appear at the end of the code provided.

I've tried rearranging the code, defining guild, and defining message. It does not seem to work even after trying all of this. I only want it to rely off of the ID instead of Name to be accurate for this command.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class woa extends commando.Command 
{
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'watchoveradd',
            group: 'help',
            memberName: 'watchoveradd',
            description: 'placeholder',
            aliases: ['woa'],
        })
    }
async run(message, args){

if (message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel) return message.channel.send('This command cannot be executed here.')
else

if(!message.member.guild.me.hasPermission(['MANAGE_WEBHOOKS'])) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the permissions to make webhooks, please contact an admin or change my permissions!')
if(!message.member.guild.me.hasPermission(['MANAGE_ROLES'])) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the permissions to make roles, please contact an admin or change my permissions!')
if (!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_WEBHOOKS'])) return message.channel.send('You need to be an admin or webhook manager to use this command.')
if (!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_ROLES'])) return message.channel.send('You need to be an admin or role manager to use this command.')

const avatar = `...`;
const name2 = "name-1.0WOCMD";

let woaID = message.mentions.channels.first(); 
if(!woaID) return message.channel.send("Channel is nonexistant or command was not formatted properly. Please do s!woa #(channelname)"); 
let specifiedchannel = message.guild.channels.find(t => t.id == woaID.id);; 
specifiedchannel.send('test');

const hook = await woaID.createWebhook(name2, avatar).catch(error => console.log(error))
await hook.edit(name2, avatar).catch(error => console.log(error))
message.channel.send("Please do not tamper with the webhook or else the command implied before will no longer function with this channel.")

setTimeout(function(){
    message.channel.send('Please wait...');
  }, 10);
setTimeout(function(){
var role = message.guild.createRole({
    name: `Name marker ${woaID.name} v1.0`,
    color: 0xcc3b3b,}).catch(console.error);

if(role.name == "name marker") {
  role.setMentionable(false, 'SBW Ping Set.')
  role.setPosition(10)
  role.setPermissions(['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'SEND_MESSAGES'])
    .then(role => console.log(`Edited role`))
    .catch(console.error)};
}, 20);

var sbwrID = member.guild.roles.find(`Synthibutworse marker ${woaID} v1.0`);
let specifiedrole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.id == sbwrID.id)

setTimeout(function(){
      message.channel.send('Created Role... Please wait.');
}, 100);

message.guild.specifiedchannel.replacePermissionOverwrites({
  overwrites: [
    {
       id: specifiedrole,
       denied: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
       allowed: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
  ],
    reason: 'Needed to change permissions'
  });

var member = client.user

var bot = message.client
bot.on('message', function(message) { {
    if(message.channel.id == sbwrID.id) {
let bannedRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.id === specifiedrole);
message.member.addRole(bannedRole);
  }
}})

}};
module.exports = woa;
```

I expect a command without the TypeError, and the command able to create a role and a webhook (for a marker), and the role is automatically set so that the user that has the role won't be able to speak in the channel, and whoever speaks in the channel will get the role.
The actual output is a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined` but a role and webhook are created.

Answer (score 0):

You have `var sbwrID = member.guild...`
You did not define member. Use `message.member.guild...`

You can setup a linter ( https://discordjs.guide/preparations/setting-up-a-linter.html ) to find these problems automatically.

Comment: this worked, but after this another issue appeared. It's now saying `Error: Value must be specified.`

Comment: It would help if you can get a stack trace